# Cannot reference a function by its name when wrapped with parenthesis

Tags: javascript

When creating a function with a name and wrapping it with parenthesis or passing it as an argument/callback to another function. An error is thrown when you try to reference that function later *by its name*.

Example:

```
(function name1(){});
console.log(name1); // throws error: name1 is not defined
```

Example:

```
plugin.module(function name2(){});
name2(); // throws error: name2 is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

The `function` keyword does two similar but distinctly different things:

1. It introduces a *function declaration* statement;
2. It introduces a *function expression*.

Both of those things create a function, but the former (function *declaration*) also binds the function name (required in that case) into the local scope. A function *expression*, however, does *not* bind the function name into the local scope. The name is bound only in the scope of the created function (that is, *inside* the function).

When `function` is the first token in a statement, it's a function declaration. Otherwise, it's a function expression. Thus when you use parentheses around the `function` statement, it's no longer a statement; it's an expression.

Answer (score 1):

Some ways to solve:

```
function name1(){ //declaration instead of expression
 //...
}

name1();
```

or a bit uglier:

```
let name1;
(name1 = function(){/*...*/})();
name1();
```